# The meaning of bargain for

Tags: phrase-meaning

Suppose we have the following piece of text:

> He sold you out. Thought to come to me and bargain for his life. So I
>   offer you the satisfaction.

What is the phrase "bargain for" there?

Comment: Have you read through all the verb uses of *bargain* in your dictionary?

Comment: @choster yeah, the meaning for bargain for is _Be prepared for; expect_. Can one fit there?

Comment: Ah, it is a parsing issue. It is *[bargain][for his life]* not *[bargain for][his life]*, *bargain* meaning to negotiate a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He sold you out. Thought to come to me and **bargain for** his life. So I offer you the satisfaction.

It is similar to "plead for" or "beg for" one's life.  Except it suggests than rather than appeal to someone's sense of compassion and humanity, the person doing the begging wants to strike a deal.  Compare:

> I was going to have him killed.  He thought to come and **plead for** his life.  Told me [he had nine kids](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYHlxqQkXFg).  I took mercy on him...and said I'd let him live if he shaved his mustache.

To:

> I was going to have him killed.  He thought to come and **bargain for** his life.  He said if I didn't kill him, he would upvote all my questions on English Language Users from now on, and write comments saying how awesome a person I seemed to be.  I said that sounded a fair deal, and let him live.

But in the quote you cite, it sounds very "Mafia" and gangster.  I hear it as: A powerful criminal is speaking to another criminal friend about someone who "snitched" on him to the authorities.  When the "snitch" found out that he was in trouble with the powerful criminal and was going to pay for his disloyalty, he tried to come cut a deal with the powerful criminal to not have him killed.  The powerful person wasn't impressed, but rather than kill the "snitch" himself he is turning him over to the person who was snitched on to exact revenge personally.